# Cant add standard .Net references to project

Tags: asp.net-core

How to add standard .Net references such as

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

When trying

```
using (System.Drawing.Image I)
```

I get the error

```
Severity    Description File    Line
Error   The type name 'Image' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcdxxxxx' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

When going into reference VS 2018 wants me to point to the DLL File.
Its really frustrating. This is a Asp.NetCore MVC web based project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Drawing` is incompatible with .NET Core, because it uses Windows-specific APIs not available in .NET Core. Microsoft has since released `System.Drawing.Common`, which is a NuGet package that provides a similar API to the old `System.Drawing` but uses cross-platform APIs. To make this truly a drop-in replacement, the `System.Drawing` namespace now forwards to `System.Drawing.Common`, so older code could work without change.

Long and short, you need to add the [`System.Drawing.Common`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) NuGet package to your project.